# error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern Spacy

Tags: python-2.7, spacy

I created a customized Spacy model using https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py and when I am loading this model. It shows an error - look-behind requires fixed-width pattern. I am confused about how to solve this issue. Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
output_dir = 'NLP_entity/model'
print("Loading from", output_dir)
nlp2 = spacy.load("NLP_entity/model")
test_text = "Remove from account"
#print()
doc2 = nlp1(test_text)
print(test_text)
#print()
if doc2.ents:
    for ent in doc2.ents:
        print("entity = {}, text = {}".format(ent.label_, ent.text))
else:
    print("Entities in None")

Error:
('Loading from', 'NLP_entity/model')

errorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-94981b2ca322> in <module>()
      2 output_dir = 'NLP_entity/model'
      3 print("Loading from", output_dir)
----> 4 nlp2 = spacy.load("NLP_entity/model")
      5 test_text = "Remove from account".decode("utf-8")
      6 #print()

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.pyc in load(name, **overrides)
     25     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     26         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 27     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     28 
     29 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.pyc in load_model(name, **overrides)
    131             return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
    132         if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
--> 133             return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **overrides)
    134     elif hasattr(name, "exists"):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    135         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.pyc in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, **overrides)
    171             component = nlp.create_pipe(name, config=config)
    172             nlp.add_pipe(component, name=name)
--> 173     return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
    174 
    175 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/language.pyc in from_disk(self, path, exclude, disable)
    784             # Convert to list here in case exclude is (default) tuple
    785             exclude = list(exclude) + ["vocab"]
--> 786         util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
    787         self._path = path
    788         return self

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/util.pyc in from_disk(path, readers, exclude)
    609         # Split to support file names like meta.json
    610         if key.split(".")[0] not in exclude:
--> 611             reader(path / key)
    612     return path
    613 

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/language.pyc in <lambda>(p)
    774         deserializers["meta.json"] = lambda p: self.meta.update(srsly.read_json(p))
    775         deserializers["vocab"] = lambda p: self.vocab.from_disk(p) and _fix_pretrained_vectors_name(self)
--> 776         deserializers["tokenizer"] = lambda p: self.tokenizer.from_disk(p, exclude=["vocab"])
    777         for name, proc in self.pipeline:
    778             if name in exclude:

tokenizer.pyx in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.from_disk()

tokenizer.pyx in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.from_bytes()

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in compile(pattern, flags)
    192 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    193     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
--> 194     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    195 
    196 def purge():

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in _compile(*key)
    249         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    250     except error, v:
--> 251         raise error, v # invalid expression
    252     if not bypass_cache:
    253         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Comment: Are you training and loading your model with the same version of spaCy? It looks like your custom model might be incompatible with the version of spaCy that you're running. You can check this by looking at the version in your model's `meta.json`. If you've recently upgraded spaCy to v2.1, you also need to retrain your model(s).

Comment: I checked the version, thank you for the solution.